# Copy a file to HoloLens emulator

Tags: hololens-emulator

I have a UWP application that allows a user to pick a file (using a file selection dialog). I can run the application inside of the HoloLens emulator. The file selection dialog seems to be working correctly. However, there are no files to choose from !

I want to copy a file from my local file system into the emulator so that the application has something to work with. How do I do that?

[EDIT]

Below is an image of the File Explorer for "PublicDocuments". Here, files can be uploaded. However, the "PublicDocuments" folder isn't visible from inside the emulator.

[image: PublicDocuments]

Below is an image of the File Explorer for "Documents". The buttons "Choose File" and "Upload" are not visible.

[image: Documents]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open any folder and scroll down - the Upload button is at the very bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Device Portal for this.  Open Device Portal for the emulator (using the globe icon on the toolbar) and browse to the File Explorer page.  You can upload files to user folders such as the Documents folder, as well as to the storage folders for your in-development app.

Comment: The only folder that I can upload a file to is called "PublicDocuments". I can see buttons that say "Choose File" and "Upload" for that folder but not any other folder. Also, the "PublicDocuments" folder isn't visible from inside the emulator... How do I upload a file to the "Documents" folder (for example)?

Comment: The emulator uses a Visitor account by default, meaning there is no specific user.  In the Tools window of the emulator, you can enable signing in with a Microsoft Account.  That will introduce extra steps when the emulator starts (specifically, you'll need to complete sign-in), but you will then have a real user account.